# Increasing the width of a rotated UIView

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UIView that I rotated using:

```
view.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle: (CGFloat.pi / 2) * 1.5)
```

This rotates my view 45 degrees. I am trying to animate this view so that it extends its width using:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, animations: { 
view.frame.size.width = 150 })
```

When I run the app the view does not transform correctly. It's width extends, but so does its height. The attached image shows what I am trying to do. Does anybody have any suggestions on how I can animate this view?

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eF3Ke.png) | [After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuKjG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation for `UIView frame`:

> Changes to this property can be animated. However, if the transform property contains a non-identity transform, the value of the frame property is undefined and should not be modified. In that case, you can reposition the view using the center property and adjust the size using the bounds property instead.

So instead of animating the `frame`, animate the `bounds`.

Comment: I tried animating the bounds and the transformation looks much butter, but loses its x-value. The view moved to the left. Is there any way to make sure the view maintains its position after the transformation?

Comment: As the quote states, you need to set the `center`. So set the `center` in addition to the `bounds`.

Comment: Sorry, i'm still new to coding swift. Could you show me how to do that or give me an example?

Comment: `view.center = CGPoint(x: someX, y: someY)`

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. This has been a big help.